# Computing Jacobian matrix of a multivariate Matrix form Function

Tags: python

I have a system of non linear equations which I need to solve to 'vars' (see code), and i'm struggling to obtain its Jacobian matrix.

I defined my F - F[0] to F[13] (matrix which represents the fn(x)=0 equations of the system) like:

```
def func(vars):
    k0 = 1597.59
    k1 = 1597.59
    k2 = 1597.59
    k3 = 1597.59
    kmenos1 = 1597.59
    tcabo = 10000
    f1max = 2398
    f2max = 4796
    f3max = 4796
    y4 = -30
    y_1ref = -3
    y_2ref = -4.5
    y_3ref = -15
    y_0ref = -3
    y_menos1ref = -3
    y_menos2ref = -3
    f1ref = 1199
    f2ref = 2398
    f3ref = 2398


    flmen1 = vars[0]
    fl0 = vars[1]
    f1 = vars[2]
    f2 = vars[3]
    f3 = vars[4]
    xmen2 = vars[5]
    xmen1 = vars[6]
    xzero = vars[7]
    x1 = vars[8]
    x2 = vars[9]
    x3 = vars[10]
    x4 = vars[11]
    ymen2 = vars[12]
    ymen1 = vars[13]
    yzero = vars[14]
    y1 = vars[15]
    y2 = vars[16]
    y3 = vars[17]
    y4 = vars[18]
    lmen10 = vars[19]
    l01 = vars[20]
    l12 = vars[21]
    l23 = vars[22]
    l34 = vars[23]


    f1eq5 = f1ref - k1 * (y1 - y_1ref)
    f2eq7 = f2ref - k2 * (y2 - y_2ref)
    f3eq9 = f3ref - k3 * (y3 - y_3ref)


    F = np.empty(14)
    F[0] = flmen1 + kmenos1 * (ymen1 - y_menos1ref)
    F[1] = flmen1 + tcabo * ((ymen1 - ymen2) / (xmen1 - xmen2)) - tcabo * ((yzero - ymen1) / (xzero - xmen1))
    F[2] = fl0 + k0 * (yzero - y_0ref)
    F[3] = fl0 + tcabo * ((yzero - ymen1) / (xzero - xmen1)) - tcabo * ((y1 - yzero) / (x1 - xzero))
    F[4] = f1 - min(f1eq5, f1max)
    F[5] = tcabo * ((y2 - y3) / (x3 - x2)) - fl0 - f1 - f2
    F[6] = f2 - min(f2eq7, f2max)
    F[7] = tcabo * ((y3 - y4) / (x4 - x3)) - fl0 - f1 - f2 - f3
    F[8] = f3 - min(f3eq9, f3max)
    F[9] = lmen10 - sqrt((yzero - ymen1) ** 2 + (xzero - xmen1) ** 2)
    F[10] = l01 - sqrt((y1 - yzero) ** 2 + (x1 - xzero) ** 2)
    F[11] = l12 - sqrt((y2 - y1) ** 2 + (x2 - x1) ** 2)
    F[12] = l23 - sqrt((y3 - y2) ** 2 + (x3 - x2) ** 2)
    F[13] = l34 - sqrt((y4 - y3)) ** 2 + (x4 - x3 ** 2)


    Fx = np.matrix([F[0], F[1], F[2], F[3], F[4], F[5], F[6], F[7], F[8], F[9], F[10], F[11], F[12], F[13]])
    return Fx
```

What should be the best way to obtain the Jacobian matrix of this F ?

To help and put into context, the system is to be solved numerically through some iterative method like Newton Raphson or Conjugate Gradients, for example. Some of these equations do not have analytical derivative. So my aim is to be able to create a function that returns the Jacobian in order that I could lately call it into a non linear iterative solver, and in that case Jacobian will always be filled with real numbers.

Anyone who could help, I appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md) should be able to compute the Jacobian with automatic differentiation. The wrinkle is that array element assignment isn't supported, so you'd need to build `F` differently -- not a huge deal though.

Comment: Thank you. What should then be the best way for me to build F in order that autograd could perform its Jacobian computing ?

Comment: You can't use element-wise array assignment, so you'll need to get rid of the intermediate array `F`. As an aside, `np.matrix` is deprecated in favor of `np.array`.